# How to get SHA-512 hashing in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

as I'm very new to this field i don't have much knowledge in this domain. I want to achieve SHA-512 secure hashing in my Application. I' using,

```
EVP_get_digestbyname((const char*)[digestName UTF8String]);
```

and passing 'SHA512' in digestname...it was working when i was passing SHA1, but will it work when I pass SHA512 as parameter?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829068/hash-a-password-string-using-sha512-like-c-sharp

Comment: But will it work? hmmm have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228092/how-can-i-compute-a-sha-2-ideally-sha-256-or-sha-512-hash-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a SHA-512 hash, use `CC_SHA512` or the related functions.  Run `man CC_SHA512` in Terminal for information.

If you want a SHA-512 HMAC, use `CCHmac` or the related functions, with `kCCHmacAlgSHA512` as the algorithm argument.  Run `man CCHmac` in Terminal for information.