# How to verify the integrity of a downloaded file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, networking, nsurlconnection

StoreKit has a bug that can lead to incomplete downloads being marked as "Finished".

I have seen some apps that download large files after In-App Purchases do an integrity check on them. How is this done?

Comment: Typically, one compares the lengths of the original file and the downloaded file, and then one uses a hash function to generate a finger print for the downloaded file, which one compares to the original file. The current standard is SHA512; the older MD5 is now considered insecure.  See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580761/how-to-get-sha-512-hashing-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I do in my own app is to pass a JSON with a list of resources will be downloading. Beside passing the URL of the resource, I also pass the checksum of it. After the download for a given file I compared the checksum I have from the JSON with the checksum of the file itself. You can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524604/md5-algorithm-in-objective-c).