# How can I hash a NSString to SHA512

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash

I have one quick question... 
I am building a social media network site app and I need to hash the password NSString. How would I accomplish this? I have the password field on the app and would like to hash the string and encode it in SHA512 for the POST request. 
Thanks in advance, 
TechnologyGuy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compute a SHA-2 (ideally SHA 256 or SHA 512) hash in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228092/how-can-i-compute-a-sha-2-ideally-sha-256-or-sha-512-hash-in-ios)

Answer (score 8):

Already answered: [hash a password string using SHA512 like C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829068/hash-a-password-string-using-sha512-like-c-sharp)

But here's the copy-pasted code:

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
+ (NSString *) createSHA512:(NSString *)source {

    const char *s = [source cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

    CC_SHA512(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);

    NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    return [out description];
}
```

Or if you prefer a hashed output, try this:

```
+(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I got this working by adding `(CC_LONG)` in front of all references to data.length. Is that correct? I think it is? Also, I found that I could add it to my AppDelegate implementation if I changed the `+(NSString...` to a `-(NSString...`. I'm kind of new with ObjC, so, is that good to do in this case? Anyway, it works for me.

Comment: I didn't see in your routine how to add a salt. So, I did it a simple way by prepending a salt string (of characters) to the input string before calling `createSHA512`.

Comment: In your bottom example data should be [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:strlen(string)]; It'd be better to use [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSData *)sha512:(NSData *)data {
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA512([data bytes], [data length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];        
        return sha1;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Put this in a category on `NSData`, or use it whatever way you like, the code remains the same.

You should've researched your question. I found an answer in one google search.

Comment: I have found other answers and did my research but the question still remains... How do I connect the password NSString to this method and how to I get the hashed SHA512 as a NSString?

Comment: @TechnologyGuy Honestly, if you can't figure *that* out…

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for answering my question.