# Error: Use of unresolved Identifier 'Process'

Tags: swift

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Swift Version: 3.0 Preview 6

I'm following this [getting started page](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-build-system)

In `greeter.swift`

```
func sayHello(name: String) {
  print("Hello, \(name)!")
}
```

in `main.swift`

```
if Process.arguments.count != 2 {
    print("Usage: hello NAME")
} else {
    let name = Process.arguments[1]
    SayHello(name: name)
}
```

Error I receive

```
$ swift build
Compile Swift Module 'myapp' (2 sources)
/Sources/main.swift:1:4: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Process'
if Process.arguments.count != 2 {
   ^~~~~~~
/Sources/main.swift:4:16: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Process'
    let name = Process.arguments[1]
               ^~~~~~~
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): swift/bin/swift-build-tool -f .build/debug.yaml
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Process was changed to CommandLine in swift 3.0

Try replacing `Process` with `CommandLine`

---

Here is the link to the commit that changed it: 
[Rename Process to CommandLine [SE-0086].](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/f65c1390cb23395fde5a798fb6731b32a31ec452)

Comment: @ChristianAbella: `CommandLine` is part of core Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CommandLine.swift. See also https://github.com/jatoben/CommandLine/issues/77.